# Streaming Webcam with RTSP

Tags: stream, webcam, rtsp, gstreamer, v4l2

I'm trying a live streaming of video  using a web cam attached to my laptop. I am working in Linux Ubuntu.

Here are the Gstreamer pipeline for server side and client side:

**Streaming server:** I'm trying to use gst-rtsp-server to serve the video from a v4l2 device.

> ./test-launch --gst-debug=0 "( v4l2src
>   !
>   video/x-raw-yuv,width=352,height=288,framerate=15/1
>   ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96
>   )"

**Receiver:**

> gst-launch -v rtspsrc
>   location=rtsp://192.168.XX.XX:8554/test
>   ! decodebin ! autovideosink

I have this message error:

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED …
>   ERROR: Pipeline doesn’t want to pause.
>   ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Could
>   not read from resource. Additional debug info: gstrtspsrc.c(4573):
>   gst_rtspsrc_send (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTSPSrc:rtspsrc0: Got
>   error response: 503 (Service Unavailable).
>   Setting pipeline to NULL …
>   Freeing pipeline …

Who know this problem and/or can try to help me?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You will get lot of examples here for receiver(client) and sender(server) application : http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-good/tree/tests/examples/rtp

Comment: None of these pipelines solve the problem. I have the same issue, the problem is probably with the camera format and v4l2.

Answer (score 1):

There might be several reasons for a stream not to be available, and that `HTTP 503` is not that clear (that error message about PAUSED state either, since a stream has to switch to every state from NULL to PLAYING, and it is necessarily already playing while switching to PAUSED).

You better add `GST_DEBUG={1,9}` before your command as in,

```
GST_DEBUG=3 ./test-launch --gst-debug=0 ...
```

In my case it was,

```
ERROR GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:691:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: no element "x264enc"
ERROR GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:776:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has no sink [source=@0x7f62b800a0d0]
ERROR GST_PIPELINE grammar.y:776:priv_gst_parse_yyparse: link has no source [sink=@0x7f62b801a1b0]
```

And I solved it by installing the package `gstreamer-plugins-ugly-orig-addon` on an openSUSE system. Hope this helps somebody to tear less hair off.